# Largest subfields common to all hyperreal fields

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

Suppose we build the hyperreal numbers $^*\Bbb R$ in the usual way as an ultrapower of the reals, built as a quotient of $\omega$-length sequences of reals mod some non-principal ultrafilter. Then, in general, we will get different hyperreal fields for different choices of ultrafilter.

However, there will be certain commonalities that all hyperreal fields share. For instance, no matter what ultrafilter you choose, we will always have that the sequence $\epsilon = (1/1, 1/2, 1/3, ...)$ is infinitesimal in the sense that we can show $\epsilon < 1/n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Thus, we can also show that all hyperreal fields will have infinitesimal (and infinitely large) elements.

Thus, we may ask if there is some "least common denominator" of all the hyperreal fields. For instance: what is the largest field that injects into all of the hyperreals simultaneously? Clearly this will be strictly larger than the real numbers, since all hyperreals have infinitesimals. It will also have to be larger than the field of rational functions (or Laurent series?) $\Bbb R(\epsilon)$, since every hyperreal element has a square root, and thus so must $\epsilon$. The Puiseux series would seem to do, but is there anything strictly larger? The Levi-Civita field?

I am also interested in substructures larger than fields; in general if there is some "maximal substructure" with "as much transfer as possible" which is common to all of the hyperreals, although I may make a separate question for that.

Comment: Well, I had suggested the field of Laurent series, but what about the field of rational functions in one infinitesimal $\epsilon$? That is a non-Archimedean field extension of the reals (the smallest?) which is the field of fractions in the polynomial ring $\Bbb R[\epsilon]$, and so as long as we are mapping $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, the entire thing is determined by where $\epsilon$ goes, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, yes, I was overcomplicating things.

Comment: (Still not sure if I understand well) If you ask the same question with $\mathbb C$ and require the embedding to be elementary, the answer is "yes": any extension of $\mathbb C$ with degree of transcendence 1 (they are all isomorphic) is minimal proper elementary extension. I guess the same holds for $\mathbb R$, or doesn't it?

Comment: Assuming CH, there is a unique hyperreal field up to isomorphism (since the ultrapower has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ and is $\aleph_1$-saturated and satisfies the complete theory of $\mathbb{R}$, and any two elementarily equivalent saturated structures of the same cardinality are isomorphic). So under CH your question has a trivial answer: the maximal field which embeds into all the hyperreal fields is the unique hyperreal field itself. So the answer to your question depends on the background set theory...

Comment: Alex Is right. Does rephrasing the question in terms of elementary extensions in place of ultrapowers comes closer to what you have in mind?

Comment: @AlexKruckman that is a good point. If we don't have the CH, is there a unique intersection or common subfield of all the different hyperreal fields?

Comment: @AlexKruckman also, do we get the same result if we extend the theory beyond just addition and multiplication? For instance, do we get something unique extension if we add $\exp$ and $\log$, or all elementary functions, or all analytic functions, etc?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia The argument is very general and applies to any countable language. If you add *all* analytic functions, the language is uncountable, and we no longer obtain saturation.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about the "intersection" of all ultrapowers, since they have different underlying sets. What I can say is that without CH, $\aleph_1$-saturation implies that every ordered field of  cardinality $\leq\aleph_1$ embeds in every ultrapower.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should clarify. I had thought that, even with CH, there are still different non-isomorphic hyperreal models, but they are all simply isomorphic *as fields*. But it seems like you are saying we get the result for countable language. So clealy if we add $\exp$ and $\log$, that's countable, and also instead of adding *all* functions, that's uncountable. So what if we add something like all "first-order definable functions", of which there are only countably many. Then with CH, do all hyperreal structures agree on this fragment?

Comment: "First-order definable" in what language? If you mean the language of fields, you don't get anything very interesting: certainly not exp and log. To be precise, the theorem is: assuming CH, if we view $\mathbb{R}$ as an $L$-structure in a countable language $L$, then for any two non-principal ultrafilters on $\omega$, the two ultrapowers of $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic as $L$-structures.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the largest possible amount of "transfer" which is common to all hyperreals we can build as ultrapowers of $R$, going with your point that CH simplifies things. So I thought that, rather adding $\exp$ and $\log$ individually, perhaps we could look at adding all of the first-order definable functions (meaning in ZFC, I guess), of which there will be countably many. Would all of those transfer to a unique field of hyperreals?

Comment: As I said: any countable language. Careful, though: if your meta-theory is ZFC, it can't even talk about the concept "ZFC-definable", so you can't prove anything about "all definable functions".

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Of course one could add an inaccessible cardinal. I am mostly interested, though, in seeing how this relates to other common non-Archimedean fields. For instance, the Levi-Civita field has a kind of transfer principle for (most?) real-analytic functions, including ones which aren't first-order definable. Does that mean that as a field, the Levi-Civita field is strictly smaller than the hyperreals, but when other functions are included beyond addition and multiplication, it doesn't embed?

Comment: I would be happy to accept this as an answer, btw, rather than in the comments section here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting some comments into an answer...

The answer to your question depends on the background set theory. If we assusme CH, then there is a unique hyperreal field up to isomorphism (since the ultrapower has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ and is $\aleph_1$-saturated and satisfies the complete theory of $\mathbb{R}$, and any two elementarily equivalent saturated structures of the same cardinality are isomorphic). So the maximal field which embeds into all the hyperreal fields is the unique hyperreal field itself.

You ask about languages other than the field language. To be precise, what the argument above proves is the following: assuming CH, if we view $\mathbb{R}$ as an $L$-structure in *any* countable language $L$, then for any two non-principal ultrafilters $U$ and $U'$ on $\omega$, the two ultrapowers $\mathbb{R}^\omega/U$ and $\mathbb{R}^\omega/U'$ are isomorphic as $L$-structures.

Without CH, one should be careful how to phrase the question. One way to interpret it is this: consider the embeddability pre-order on the class of all fields which embed into all hyperreal fields. It's not clear to me that this pre-order has a maximum class.